# LINQ orderby FK using a left join

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have the following code:

```
from _categories in context.SCT_Categories
join _categoryOrders in context.SCT_CategoryOrders
on _categories.ID equals _categoryOrders.CategoryID into joinedData
from _categoryOrders in joinedData.DefaultIfEmpty()
orderby _categoryOrders.OrderIndex descending 
select _categories
```

Which does a left join on categories and categoryOrders

For every catgoryOrder there is a category.

This works well, except that when I want to order by OrderIndex (Can be null to 999) it places all empty (i.e. null returned relationships where a category has no categoryOrder) at the top of the query.

How do I change this to put empty values at the end of the list? Prefereably without an iteration after the query to change empty values to 999.

Thanks,

JD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tried this (the IQueryProvider might not like it)

```
let orderIndex = _categoryOrders.OrderIndex ?? int.MaxValue
```

Right before your orderby, and order on orderIndex instead.

Comment: Perfect! I had to cast the int to int? first, but this worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: Final code: `from _categories in context.SCT_Categories
join _categoryOrders in context.SCT_CategoryOrders
on _categories.ID equals _categoryOrders.CategoryID into joinedData
from _categoryOrders in joinedData.DefaultIfEmpty()
let orderIndex = ((int?)_categoryOrders.OrderIndex) ?? int.MaxValue
orderby orderIndex ascending  
select _categories`

Answer (score 1):

You could try sorting those with non-null values first, and addind the null values last:

```
var categories = from _categories in context.SCT_Categories
    join _categoryOrders in context.SCT_CategoryOrders
    on _categories.ID equals _categoryOrders.CategoryID into joinedData
    from _categoryOrders in joinedData.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select _categories;


var sortedCategories = categories.Where(c=>c.OrderIndex != null).OrderBy(c=>c.OrderIndex)
    .union(categories.Where(c=>c.OrderIndex == null));
```

Comment: Thanks Gerardo. This would work, however I was looking for a solution using the least amount of operations possible. `let`, suggested by JeffN825 let me do this. Thanks again, JD

Comment: You are right. To tell the truth, I started writing the answer before Jeff's answer appeared. I googled it and learned something new! StackOverflow is good.